# EPERM error: operation not permitted, open '..\tmp\build.lock'

Tags: ember.js

A build error is encountered like :EPERM: operation not permitted, open '..\tmp\build.lock' while a reload needs to be done to the web page after editing a javascript file. Ember Js is used at the front end with Ember-cli version is 2.4.3 and node.js is 7.9.0. Windows 10 64bit is the OS. After this error the ember serve stops and the terminal hangs up. But this is working fine with Mac.Please help me out.

```
Error details are as follws:

EPERM: operation not permitted, open '..\tmp\build.lock'
________________________________________
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '..\tmp\build.lock'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
    at Class.preBuild (..\node_modules\ember-cli-rails-addon\index.js:38:10)
    at ..\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:144:34
    at Array.map (native)
    at Class.processAddonBuildSteps (..\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:142:43)
    at Class.build (..\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:163:17)
    at Watcher_build [as build] (..\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\index.js:75:6)
    at Watcher.<anonymous> (..\node_modules\broccoli-sane-watcher\index.js:43:17)
    at tryCatch (..\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (..\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
```

Comment: Are you running ember-cli in an administrator shell?

Comment: no...but i have tried out that also.. running ember-cli in administrator shell..but the result was same.

Comment: you should *always* run ember-cli in an Administrator shell btw.

Answer (score 1):

1. Completely remove tmp folder
2. Create new tmp folder
3. Right click tmp folder and grant all permissions recursive in Windows dialog
4. Then right click whole project directory and also grant all permissions recursively in Windows dialog (read, write etc.)

Comment: Had tried with these steps bt the same issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

reboot your machine, maybe something is using that file